# How to place the item to the right side of the screen instead of center?

Tags: android, xml

[image]I've been using android studio and xml to design my application. I've wanted to make my "Hi,user", logout button, receipt button and cart move to the right of the screen. How should i change my xml to make it like this?

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="#33CC33" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Logout"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.06" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Receipt"
                android:id="@+id/receipt_button"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.06" />

            <RelativeLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/myButton"
                    android:layout_width="65dip"
                    android:layout_height="65dip"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/cart"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textOne"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/myButton"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/myButton"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:textColor="#FFF"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set "layout_gravity" as right to align right

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:textColor="#33CC33" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Logout"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.06" />

</LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Receipt"
            android:id="@+id/receipt_button"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.06" />

        <RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/myButton"
                android:layout_width="65dip"
                android:layout_height="65dip"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:background="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/cart"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textOne"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/myButton"
                android:layout_alignRight="@id/myButton"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="@drawable/badge_circle"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```